# How to exclude the entire expression and not just the first part with negative look-behind in block text

Tags: python, html, regex, email, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to extract all e-mails from HTML except for e-mails preceded by a mailto: tag.

It works except when someone has a . in their e-mail address which is fairly common - I've tried look-aheads, different kinds of boundaries and I just can't seem to get regex to exclude the entire e-mail if it has a . in it and is preceded by a mailto: tag

Regex:
`(?<!mailto:)(\b[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)`

Test string:
`Maecenas sed diam eget risus fake.name@domain.net varius blandit sit amet non magna. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Maecenas faucibus <a href="mailto:fake.name@domain.net">fake.name@domain.net</a> mollis interdum.`

The first and last match are fine the 2nd match is .name@domain.net when I don't want it to match at all.

Comment: See [Regex Pattern to Match, Excluding when… / Except between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between)

Comment: There is a simpler approach: use BeautifulSoup to remove all `href`s with `mailto:` and then run `re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+', remaining_plain_text)`

Comment: Are you using BeautifulSoup already?

Comment: I have an approach that works by removing the hrefs with mailto but it's not suitable. I need a solution to do this in one regex

Comment: So, you are extracting? But you will still need to write some code. Try `[y for x,y in re.findall(r'(mailto:[^>\s]*?)?\b([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)', text) if not x]` - see [this demo](https://ideone.com/npSuOQ).

Comment: If you have PyP regex  module you can do it with a single call to `regex.findall`, like `regex.findall(r'\b(?<!mailto:[^>\s]*?)\w[\w.-]*@[\w.-]+\.[\w.-]+', text)`